# Json.NET decode multidimensional array

Tags: c#, php, json.net

I am a newbie in .Net and I am creating a desktop application to my website. I am passing data using JSON and **Json.NET** However I am receiving an error every time I try to decode this string. What could possibly be wrong? How do I decode a multidimensional array.

This is the string I am decoding

```
{
   "api_ver":"1.0",
   "request":"user-account-exists",
   "date":"2014-08-25 09:57:16",
   "data":
   {
      "user_account_exists":1
   }
}
```

My code is here

```
json_data = string.Empty;
try
{                
    json_data = webclient.DownloadString("http://api.mysite.com/?ruser-account-exists");
}
catch (Exception e)
{                
    Logger.Log(e.Message);
}

_api = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<api>(json_data) : 
                                          new api();
```

The error is as shown below

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'data', line
>   1, position 86.

I want to deserialize this array into a dictionary

Comment: Paste your json to http://json2csharp.com/ and see how your classes should be declared

Comment: You say that you are trying to deserialize into a dictionary but your code is deserializing into an object `api` which is confusing. This error is occuring because the `api` class does not model the data correctly. Model the data using the above link or use `dynamic` instead.

Comment: please show us your api class ?

Comment: @LB solution works perfectly. You should have posted this as an answer and I would have gladly accepted. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the `api` class does not model the json sufficiently.

The model should resemble the following one (generated using [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)):

```
public class Api
{
    public string api_ver { get; set; }
    public string request { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int user_account_exists { get; set; }
}
```

Optionally you could use `dynamic`

```
dynamic values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_data);
bool exists = (int) values.data.user_account_exists == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ?

```
public class api
{
    public string api_ver { get; set; }
    public string request { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int user_account_exists { get; set; }
}

api apiObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<api>(json_data) ;
```